# Disallow page closing in Xamarin.iOS during background actions

Tags: xamarin.ios

In my IoT mobile app, I created a page showed on iOS device as `UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet`.

During the page load I don't want the page will react to user interaction, in particular I don't want the page will be closed, because the app interacts with a physical device.
The page will be enabled to be closed once all the background tasks will be completed.

I tried to set the page property `IsEnabled` to false, but again I'm able to close the page.

That's a code snippet from the page constructor

```
public ParametersListPage(ControlUnitParametersCategory parametersCategory, bool isParametersListReadOnly = false)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsEnabled = false;
        
        On<iOS>().SetModalPresentationStyle(UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet);

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ListParamsViewModel>(this, Constants.ACTION, async (sender) =>
            {
                IsEnabled = true;
                await DisplayAlert(Resource.DoAct, Resource.DoActMsg, "OK");
            }
        );
```

What Am I missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to disable user actions during interaction? If so, you can try setting the UserInteractionEnabled property to false to disable the user's actions so that the user will never be able to trigger any events (including touchscreens).
For Xamarin.Forms you can refer to the following code:

MyPageRenderer:

```
[assembly:ExproRenderer(typeof(ParametersListPage),typeof(ParametersListPageRenderer))]
namespace FormsDemo.iOS
{
 public class ParametersListPageRenderer:PageRenderer
    {
         protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           this.View.UserInteractionEnabled=false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want the user not to close the page during interaction, it is better to set a popup reminder.